# Проблема прокрутки overflow на мобильном устройстве

Tags: html, css

Всем привет. Столкнулся с одной проблемкой. У меня прокрутка реализована через overflow:hidden; , на пк все работает отлично, но когда пытаешься прокручивать на телефоне, то сначала надо тыкнуть на div(ленту новостей) и только потом заработает прокрутка, до этого если пытаться прокручивать ленту новостей, то прокручивается вся страница.

Много чего пробовал и ничего не повезло.
Пробовал фиксировать элементы, пробовать webkit-skrollbar и т.д...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Стоит попробовать поставить overflow:auto; Скорей всего скрипт строит под мобильное отображение свои теги. Надо посмотреть код, чтобы знать что там происходит.

Comment: Выше дополнил пост с кодом

Comment: Спасибо большое, попробовал просто поставить auto и все заработало четко, я сегодня целый день мучался с этой фигней, чуть ли не весь код переписывал

Answer (score 0):

Это моя реализация скрола:

```
#bk1 {
    background-clip:border-box;
    background-color: #2f3255;
    height: 1700px;
    width: 900px;
    margin-left: 250px;
    margin-right: 50px;
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 0px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    overflow:hidden;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}
```